# symfony2 ask for user password after form submit

Tags: validation, symfony

I am new to symfony and trying to log in a user but only asking for his password after the form got submitted.

So a new password field should appear if the user got one and revalidate the form after submit.

I am using a data transformer so that it can map the email string to the user entity but now I want the person to enter a password if there is one so that the user can be validated, if not the custom form should fail.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This should get you goin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422251/manual-authentication-check-symfony-2

Comment: Answer for this question has been posted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965795/validating-a-password-in-symfony2